# Why does the same MATLAB code run with different algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm using MATLAB to profile a simple fminunc code and I found that the profiler displays different algorithms when I profile the code once again.
Why is it?
The code is as below.

```
clear;
clc;
alpha = 2;
beta = 2;
nobs = 100;
start = [1;1;1];
options = optimoptions('fminunc','GradObj','off','Algorithm','quasi-newton','Display','off');
x = random('unif',1,10,nobs,1);
u = random('norm',0,4,nobs,1);
y = alpha + beta * x + u;

lnL = @(para) (1/2) * nobs * log(2 * pi) +...
    (1/2) * nobs * log(para(3))+...
    (1/2) * (para(3))^(-1) * sum((y - para(1) - x * para(2)).^2);

para_hat = fminunc(lnL,start,options);
```

And the images of profiler are as below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: hi, @rayryeng. I don't quite understand what you say. Can you explain it in more details? Thank you!

Comment: Every time you run the code, `x` and `u` are different because of random functions you chose.  These are different with each run, and that's why the run times are different.  If you make `x` and `u` **deterministic** (i.e. the **same** every time you run the code), the run times will relatively be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = random('unif',1,10,nobs,1);
u = random('norm',0,4,nobs,1);
```

This means the code will choose a random `nobs` in every time you run it. Definitely, results will be different in each time.